# How to determine keys of array-elements that have a value contained in another array in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I have two number arrays `arrAll` and `arrGood`:

```
arrAll <- c(3:12, 9:3)
arrGood <- c(3, 8)
```

I want to find out the keys of all entries in `arrAll` that have a value that is contained in ´arrGood`. In this case all keys of arrAll should be returned, where the value is either 3 or 8. Here it should give: 1, 6, 12, 17

I tried:

```
which(arrAll == arrGood)
```

Well, this does not work. It there a function like "isContainedIn" or "isElementOf" in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
> which(!arrAll %in% setdiff(arrAll, arrGood))
[1]  1  6 12 17
```

`is.element` is another function to look at...

```
> which(is.element(arrAll, arrGood))
[1]  1  6 12 17
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
which(arrAll %in% arrGood)
```